# Closed form expression for a recurrence relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

Hello, any ideas for computing closed form for a recurrence relation?

In an attempt to compute what the $i$-th post order element would be in terms of its in order position in a complete binary tree, I could arrive at following recurrence relation:

For each $k$, $f_k \in S_{2^{k+1} - 1} $ i.e. it is a permutation on ${1,...,2^{k+1} -1 } $

\begin{cases}
f_{k} (i) = f_{k-1} (i - 2^k + 1) + 2^k, & \text{if}\; i > 2^k\\
f_{k} (i) = f_{k-1} (i),                 &\text{if}\;  i < 2^k\\
f_{k} (i) = 2^k + 1,                     &\text{if}\;  i = 2^k
\end{cases}

With this recurrence we can get the value of $ f_{k} (i) $ in $ O(\log i) $ steps, but a closed form expression would be of great help.

Comment: Is this formula written correctly?  E.g. $f_1(3)=f_0(3-2+1)+2=f_0(2)+2$, which is undefined.

Comment: What led you to the recurrence relations?